# Highcharts title alignment

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am trying to use Highcharts library.

Here I there is a simple example of a graph, I would like to align left the title at the beginning of the graph (aligned with the ylabel)
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/title/text/

I saw that there the graph created has an x attribute that find its position from the border-left of the image.
In my example x value is x="397" . If I set the x attribute in my code as `x: -320` I get the desiderd shift.
Unfortunately this is not a good solution because if I change the text in the title I lost the alignment I want (and I wolud like to create a graph where the user can change the title without lost its alignment) .

What is the best way to perform this alignment ?

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For align the title just use `align:left` in your js

```
title: {
        text: 'My custom title',
        align: 'left'
    }
```

[Check Your Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/4c9qhgdo/)